# dhcpd.conf configuration for PXE server

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, pxe, dhcpd

i am trying to configure the dhcpd.conf file, when I restart and see the staus of the isc-dhcp-server it is giving below error:

```
isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: >
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-12-06 11:49:01 UTC; 1s ago
   Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
Process: 8708 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec      CONFIG_FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf;      if [ ->
Main PID: 8708 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    CPU: 27ms
Dec 06 11:49:01 pxe dhcpd[8708]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
Dec 06 11:49:01 pxe systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 06 11:49:01 pxe dhcpd[8708]: 
Dec 06 11:49:01 pxe dhcpd[8708]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug
```

Could you show the link or write the step-by-step guide how to configure the dhcpd.conf file if my example ip address is 10.10.11.99

Comment: Please edit your question and add details on which Ubuntu release you are using. Furthermore it would help if you could show the content of your current configuration file in your post.